# How transparent are Facebook's "Causes" profile picture overlays?

Tags: transparency

I'm trying to make an imitation of one of Facebook's "Causes" overlays - specifically, one that represents both the French and Lebanese flags in its design. To do this, I would like to know the exact transparency values of the overlays that Facebook allowed users to add to their profile pictures, such as the rainbow overlay from earlier this year following the SCotUS decision on gay marriage and now the one following the terrorist attacks on Paris and Beirut. An approximation would work, too, but I would prefer the exact values.

Comment: Take a gay flag and make some tests in Photoshop over another picture with layer transparency. And compare it with the real thing. I don't think there's a precise setting for this, you'll probably need to figure it out yourself and then edit your questions with some examples and tests!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did work this out a while back so I went to check it just now and they've changed the way they do it. They used to have an image overlayed at, IIRC, 50% opacity (in the CSS) but now the "customise your profile picture" overlay uses a [transparent PNG](https://scontent.fmel1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t39.1997-6/p640x640/12057049_1510669569231351_1685452394_n.png) over your profile pic.